# Django TypeError objects is not iterable

Tags: python, django

I tried to show a model data in html template in django.

**My Model:**

```
class Author(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    date_of_death = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('author_detail', args=[str(self.id)])

    class Meta():
        ordering = ['first_name', 'last_name']

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.first_name} {self.last_name}'
```

**My View:**

```
def author_detail_view(request, pk):
    author = get_object_or_404(Author, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'author_detail.html', context={'author_detail': author})
```

**My URL:**

```
 path('author/<int:pk>', views.author_detail_view, name='author_detail')

And My Templates View:
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<h1>Author Detail</h1>
    {% for author in author_detail %}
<ul>
    <li>Name: {{ author.first_name }} {{ author.last_name }}</li>
    <li>Date of Birth: {{ author.date_of_birth }}</li>
</ul>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

But the probelem is, it shoing error that :

**TypeError at /author/2**

**'Author' object is not iterable**

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/author/2
Django Version:     2.1.5
Exception Type:     TypeError
Exception Value:

'Author' object is not iterable

Exception Location:     /home/pyking/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py in render, line 165
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python3
Python Version:     3.6.7

Comment: Your `author_detail` is a *single* `Author` object, so using a `{% for author in author_detail %}` does not make much sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `author_detail` is a *single* `Author` object, so it does not make sense to iterate over it. What would be the elements over which you can iterate?

You can thus render it like:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<h1>Author Detail</h1>
<ul>
    <li>Name: {{ author_detail.first_name }} {{ author_detail.last_name }}</li>
    <li>Date of Birth: {{ author_detail.date_of_birth }}</li>
</ul>
{% endblock %}
```